# Как расширить консольное приложение по длинне?

Tags: c#

После запуска console app. то этот [черный прямоугольник](https://www.google.lv/search?q=console%20app%20c%23&rlz=1C1CHWL_ruLV735LV735&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik1JCXmNTSAhVBESwKHTC_DOUQ_AUICCgB&biw=1680&bih=920#imgrc=dHNFyReZzfjq2M:)

можно растянуть вниз до самого низа экрана, а если мне надо его по всей длине монитора растянуть, это вообще возможно ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ширина консоли измеряется в количестве текстовых символов.

[Свойство Console.WindowWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.windowwidth(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Метод Console.SetWindowSize (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.SetWindowSize(width, height);
```

Чтобы установить максимальные значения для текущего шрифта и разрешения экрана, попробуйте:

```
Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);
```